# "fetchrow"-like behavior in Neo4j (.NET Driver)?

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, graph-databases

I apologize if I'm asking an extremely basic and naïve question, but I've searched for the answer, and haven't been able to find it.

I'm a newb to Neo4j and graph databases, after working with relational databases. In relational databases, for example, I'll get a statement handle, perform a query on the database, and then be able to work on the statement handle row-by-row, that is, have a "fetchrow" function to retrieve one row at a time from the query result. I can work on the results without ingesting the whole thing at once into memory.

Now I'm working with Neo4j, in .NET/C# (with code I didn't originate), and I haven't been able to find a way to do that. The code has, for example:

```
using (var session = connection.GetDriver().Session())
{
    result = session.ReadTransaction(tx => tx.Run(query).ToList());
}
```

And retrieves the whole query result into `result`, even if that takes a very long time or overflows the available memory.

Is there no way to do a "fetchrow"-like operation with Neo4j? In my searching, I've mostly found people recommending performing queries with `SKIP` and `LIMIT`, and that isn't really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's not really a thing. If you compare Cypher to SQL, you might have some idea why it doesn't really work. In SQL, you can either have it return everything you select, or add a LIMIT clause. It's similar here.

If you were using something like python pandas or pyspark, you can get the query results into dataframes, but it still may take a long time or overflow existing memory.

You can use apoc.export functions to batch output, which could help with the memory issue. See https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/export/ for the options.

Comment: I found a way to get the behavior I was looking for. Maybe I didn't ask the question well? See my answer I posted to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get a similar behavior. This example is in Python ([API Doc](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/api.html)) but it works similarly with .NET (cf. [IResult Interface](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/dotnet-driver/current/html/f1ac31ec-c6dd-798b-b5d6-3ca0794d7502.htm)) and other drivers.

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

def do_tx(tx, cypher):
    print("do_tx:", [tx, cypher])
    result = tx.run(cypher)
    print("result:", result)
    values = []
    for record in result:  # This is equivalent to "fetchrow"
        print("record in result:", record)
        # Do whatever I want here with the incremental result
        for (value in record.values()):
            values.append(value) # Store the retrieved value
        summary = result.consume()
        return values

db = GraphDatabase(uri, auth=(user, password))
with db.session(database="neo4j") as session:
    query = "MATCH (r:Risk) RETURN DISTINCT r.score"
    result = session.write_transaction(do_tx, query)
    print(result)
```

`write_transaction()` calls `do_tx()` with a neo4j.work.transaction.Transaction object and the Cypher query. `tx.run(cypher)` runs the Cypher query and gets a neo4j.work.result.Result object. That Result object is iterable and gives Record objects.

The same could have been done in my C# code above:

```
using (var session = driver.Session())
{
    string query = "MATCH (r:Risk) RETURN DISTINCT r.score";
    var scores = session.ReadTransaction(tx => {
        List<string> results;
        var result => tx.Run(query);
        foreach (var record in result)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in record.Values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
                results.Add(kvp.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        return results;
    });
}
```

Comment: Isn't this still getting all the results from the Cypher query, but iterating through the Result object? Or am I reading this wrong / missing something?

Maybe I misunderstood your original question, but I don't think this is fundamentally different than creating a Pandas DataFrame and iterating through it. But please correct me if I'm mistaken - I am always glad to learn something! :)

Comment: Yes, you're probably right about what's happening internally -- that it's iterating through results rather than using an actual cursor -- but the behavior I was looking for was exactly that, being able to iterate through results without having to ListAll() (as the code I received did) and store a massive result that was blowing up my memory. I wanted to be able to iterate through the result and do something with it without first storing it all. As I said, I'm not sure I knew how to ask the question clearly.

Comment: Maybe the neo4j Record object is using far less memory than a dataframe. Either way, I'm glad it worked out for you!